# Default Web App in Site

Tags: iis, web-server

I have a setup like so in IIS

Server
-- Sites
---- SiteAliasInIIS
------ WebApp1
------ WebApp2
------ WebAppN

Is there any way to make WebApp 2 accessible by simply going to **localhost/SiteAliasInIIS/**

Please note that a simple meta redirect isn't possible for the application as it comes in to a specific page (other than an index) w/ querystring values.

Comment: Which version of IIS?  It might be possible via redirect rules if you're using a new enough version.

Comment: We're using 7.5